# If $d$ is a natural number and $d^2$ divides $y^2$ then does $d$ divide $y$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $d$ and $y$ are positive integers and I know that $d^{2}|2y^{2}$ then $d^2|2$ (i.e $d=1$) or $d^2|y^2$ .

In the case that $d^2|y^2$ does that imply that $d|y$ for all $d,y$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to represent $d^2$ and $y^2$ as products of prime factors, compare it with prime factorization of $d$ and $y$ and this will be enough, I hope, to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Write out as definition of divisibility:
$$d^2|y^2\implies y^2=ad^2$$
Taking the positive square root we arrive at $y=d\sqrt{a}$ therefore $d|y$ if and only if $a$ is square. Now show that, for $y$ to be square, $a$ must be square in the first place. Thus completing the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES and you can think of it using the prime factorization.